# Cloud 9 NPM not working again

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cloud9

I was testing web application in cloud 9 using node express. The npm app.js was working before suddenly it stops working. When i run npm app.js is returning the command line below : Any ideas

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,
    ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, edit, explore, get,
    help, help-search, i, init, install, install-test, it, link,
    list, ln, login, logout, ls, outdated, owner, pack, ping,
    prefix, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, tag, team, test, tst, un, uninstall,
    unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/ubuntu/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@3.10.10 /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm is the package manager. Did you mean to run `node app.js` ?

Comment: yes. I run the npm app.js but it is returning that command line instruction. It was working initially for 2 days until yesterday night.

Comment: look at me is working now am using npm app.js instead of node app.js Thanks.